# delete prime numbers from an array-java

Tags: java, arrays

How can I do in order to delete prime numbers not including 0 and 1 and I want to find just prime numbers excluding 0 and 1?Now if I have{0,1,3,5,8}----> after compiling it will find 0 and 1 as prime numbers ."Prime Number Found=0 Prime Number Found=1 Prime Number Found=3 Prime Number Found=5"  Here's my program:
Thank you for your help.

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j,size;
        boolean status;
        System.out.print("Enter size of array=");
        size=s.nextInt();
        int arr[]=new int[size];
        int tmp[]=new int[size];
        System.out.println("Enter Elements in array...");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            arr[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        for( i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            status=true;
            for(j=2;j<arr[i]-1;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]%j==0||(arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1)
                {
                    status=false;
                    tmp[i]=arr[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(status==true)
            {
                System.out.println("Prime Number Found="+arr[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("New Array....");
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(tmp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your actual question/problem?  Your code already appears to be correctly identifying prime numbers from those which the user enters.

Comment: now I have 0 and 1 as prime numbers ,but I want to exclud 0 and 1 .I've tried this with this line: if(arr[i]%j==0||(arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1) ,but nothing changes

Comment: That obviously doesn't work. Have you tried to think about if your program can reach that `if` if the number is either 0 or 1? It obviously can't.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was full of problems, but in the code below I did fix the following major problems:

- you were not handling the base case of 0 and 1 being not prime correctly
- your loop for scanning for possible whole number divisors had the wrong bounds
- you were not writing the found prime numbers correctly to the output array which you were printing at the end of the `main()` method.

Have a look at the code below for a sample of what you probably intended to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean status;
    System.out.print("Enter size of array=");
    int size = s.nextInt();
    int arr[] = new int[size];
    int tmp[] = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Enter Elements in array...");
    int primerCounter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = s.nextInt();
    }
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) {
        status = true;
        if (arr[i] == 0 || arr[i] == 1) {
            status = false;
        }
        else {
            for (int j=2; j <= arr[i]-1; j++) {
                if (arr[i] % j ==0) {
                    status = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (status == true) {
            tmp[primerCounter++] = arr[i];
            System.out.println("Prime Number Found="+arr[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("New Array....");
    for (int i=0; i < primerCounter; i++) {
        System.out.println(tmp[i]);
    }
}
```

For an input of the numbers from 0 to 20 inclusive, I got the following output:

```
{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but I am assuming your problem is that the code you posted considers 0 and 1 as prime numbers, and you don't want that. If that's the case. the error is that the check

`(arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1)`

is within the for loop

`for(j=2;j<arr[i]-1;j++)`

In fact, when arr[i] is equal to 0 or 1, the condition

```
j<arr[i]-1
```

will evaluate to false immediately, because j=2 and arr[i]-1 evaluates to either -1 or 0. As a consequence, the code

```
  if(arr[i]%j==0||(arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1)
  {
      status=false;
      tmp[i]=arr[i];
      break;
  }
```

will never be executed, and in the following loop

```
status==true
```

will evaluate to true.

One solution is to remove the check

```
arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1
```

from where it is now and put it in the same if as the one whose condition is

```
status==true
```

after changing == with !=.

In a nutshell,

```
if(arr[i]%j==0||(arr[i]==0)||arr[i]==1)
{
     status=false;
     tmp[i]=arr[i];
     break;
}
```

should become

```
if(arr[i]%j==0)
{
     status=false;
     tmp[i]=arr[i];
     break;
}
```

and

```
 if(status==true)
 {
   System.out.println("Prime Number Found="+arr[i]);
 }
```

should become

```
 if(status==true || arr[i]!=0 || arr[i]!=1)
 {
   System.out.println("Prime Number Found="+arr[i]);
 }
```

There's another mistake in the code you posted: you use the same index i to iterate over arr and to select the elements of tmp to whom assign values. As not every element of arr is prime and will not therefore be copied to tmp, this results in an array tmp with some "holes", i.e, unassigned elements. You should keep a different index k initialized to 0 to access the elements of tmp and increment it manually:

```
 tmp[k]=arr[i];
 k++;
```

instead of

```
 tmp[i]=arr[i];
```

Also, when you eventually iterate over tmp bear in mind that its size won't be the same as arr, but smaller (for the reason I have just explained). Thus,

```
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(tmp[i]);
    }
```

should be replaced with

```
    for(i=0; i < actual-size-of-tmp; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(tmp[i]);
    }
```